# Azure Virtual Applications

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, azure

So, I set up a "portal" application directory on azure as follows:
[image]

There is a WordPress site on the root:

[https://mwren-test.azurewebsites.net](https://mwren-test.azurewebsites.net/)

And an ASP.NET Application on the portal virtual directory:

https://mwren-test.azurewebsites.net/portal/

However, if you look at the portal link, none of the support files under that directory are found, hence no styling, and clicking on a link such as "about" takes you to a page not found from the wordpress site.  In other words any portal/* requests are still getting handled by the wordpress site.  How do I get the asp.net app to handle all portal/* requests on Azure?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the Kudu console:

1. Open Kudu console which is accessed via `{yoursite}.scm.azurewebsites.net`
2. Select from the Menu at the top `Debug Console` and then `Powershell`
3. Navigate to `site\wwwroot` and click the edit icon on `web.config`
4. Update the `web.config` file to include an exception for `/portal/*` as demonstrated below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
         <rules>
               <rule name="WordPress: http://{yoursite}.azurewebsites.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                   <match url="*"/>
                       <conditions>
                           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                           <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/portal/*" negate="true" />
                       </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```